use new hard drive to extend existing partition on Ubuntu
I have inherited this machine with following partition setup:

The machine runs Ubuntu 20.046 LTS and as one can see above there is 3.5T space unallocated in the partition schema. The unallocated space corresponds with separated drive. I would like to use the extra 3.5T to extend ubuntu-vg-ubuntu-lv.
I've read through some material online (e.g. this, this, this). However since I do not have much experience in this kind of work plus there is no data backup mechanism in place I do not feel confident enough with any of the solution provided above.
I'd appreciated any advice how to (relatively) safely proceed with this.

Overview
Your root filesystem sits on a logical volume named ubuntu-lv. That volume is carved out of a volume group named ubuntu-vg. The volume group (probably) contains a single physical volume, /dev/sda3. You want to:

Add a new physical volume to volume group ubuntu-vg
Grow logical volume ubuntu-lv to take advantage of the additional space
Grow the filesystem on ubuntu-lv so that you can use that space.

You can use the lvs command to list logical volumes (note that this and all following commands are run in a test environment and won't produce identical output to what you see; in particular, I don't have 1.8T of free space available):
# lvs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <5.00g <4.00g

You can use the vgs command to list volume groups:
# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <5.00g <4.00g

You can use the pvs command to list physical volumes:
# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/vdb   ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <5.00g <4.00g

Adding a physical volume

Prepare /dev/sdb for use by lvm:
pvcreate /dev/sdb

You should receive the message "Physical volume "/dev/sdb" successfully created." At this point, running pvs should now show two physical volumes:
# pvs
  PV         VG        Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/vdb   ubuntu-vg lvm2 a--  <5.00g <4.00g
  /dev/vdc             lvm2 ---   5.00g  5.00g



Extend the volume group

Add /dev/sdb to the ubuntu-vg volume group:
vgextend ubuntu-vg /dev/sdb

You should receive the message "Volume group "ubuntu-vg" successfully extended". Running vgs should show that the volume group is now larger:
# vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  ubuntu-vg   2   1   0 wz--n- 9.99g 8.99g



Grow the logical volume and the filesystem

Extend your logical volume to use the available space. Assuming that you want your filesystem to use all the available space, you can run:
lvextend -l 100%FREE -r ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

This instructs lvm to extend the logical volume to use 100% of the free space on the volume group (-l 100%FREE), and then resize the filesystem (-r).
If you want to extend by a specific amount of space, you can use the -L option. E.g., to extend your filesystem so that the total size is 2.5T, you could write:
lvextend -L 2.5T -r ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv

If you want to add a specific amount of space (as in, "make the filesystem 1T bigger"), you can do it like this instead:
lvextend -L +1T -r ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv



At this point, you should see that your logical volume is now bigger:
# lvs
  LV        VG        Attr       LSize Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 8.99g

And that your filesystem is as well:
# df -h /mnt
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  8.9G   24K  8.8G   1% /mnt


plus there is no data backup mechanism in place...

Hard drives can fail. If that data is important, you'll want to ensure you have a way to restore it.
